# activity state when pressed back button vs rotation

Tags: android

I have an object that implements Parcelable so that when the screen is rotated, the data is deserialized and display on screen. However, when I press the back button and click on activity "A" again, the data isn't there anymore. Why is onSaveInstanceState null after you press back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user knowingly leaves the `Activity`, the `onSaveInstanceState` is not called. It is called when the system destroys and recreates the `Activity`.

For this reason, you are getting `null` in `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Refer - 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29

Answer (score 3):

When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity is no longer needed.

`onSaveInstaceState` will have value only if the activity is Recreated by the system.

Check [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for more info.